# How to prevent tests with MockMvc from interfering with unit tests?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito, mockmvc

At the beginning of the project, I created several tests using only **Mockito**. Now, I started to create the first endpoint test of the project, using **MockMvc** and, therefore, many tests failed. It seems that the context introduced by this integration test changed the result of several tests that were isolated.

The biggest problem is that if I "correct" the tests with the new results and run all the tests together, everything works fine. However, when I run tests singly, they fail, because the results are back to what they were before the "correction".

**In short, I need to prevent tests with MockMvc from interfering with unit tests.**

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyEnpointsControllerTest {
   // my tests
}
```

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.Silent.class)
public class MySingleImplementationTest {
    // my tests
}
```

> **Example of what is going on:** When a I run the tests of a file, there is a static variable in somewhere, called `messageSource` that is `null`. But when I run all tests, MockMvc part starts the application which gives some value to `messageSource`. That's why my unit tests can have 2 results depending on the situation.

Comment: Try creating two profiles "integration" and "unit", then in anotate each class with either `@ActiveProfiles(value = "integration")` or `@ActiveProfiles(value = "unit")`

Comment: Creating profiles didn't work for me.

Comment: May be you should provide us much more lines of code. Like your mocked properties, and one test for each. Along with a few errors or unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Try to remove a default main test with application main class. @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest 

maybe this remove the context for default for tests.